# How to create a React Native component using JSON Schema

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a component using react-native from below JSON format. And this has to be done with-out using any third party components.

```
{
 "properties": {
      "taxDetails": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "keyValue": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "keyName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "index": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "upperBody": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "keyValue": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "keyName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "index": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "bodyItems": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "itemDetails": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "ItemValue": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "ItemPrice": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "ItemQty": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "ItemName": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "itemCount": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "paymentDetails": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "paymentMeta": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "keyValue": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "keyName": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "index": {
                  "type": "number"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "paymentType": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },  
}
```

By using the above JSON schema, I have to create a template like below.

```
<View>
   <Text>{item.keyName}</Text>
   <Text>{item.keyValue}</Text>
   <Text>{item.index}</Text>
</View>

<View>
   <Text>{item.ItemName}</Text>
   <Text>{item.ItemPrice}</Text>
   <Text>{item.ItemQty}</Text>
   <Text>{item.ItemValue}</Text>
</View>
```

If I create a template like that, I can show the values by using other JSON. So can someone please help me in creating a template like above.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox